# Get UILabel out of UIButton

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have an UIButton to which an UILabel was added as a subview.
Is there an easy way to get the UILabel back out of it so I can change it's title ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you assign a `tag` to it while you still have a reference to it, you can later find it by searching for views with that `tag`.

Like this:

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init...];
label.tag = 1000;
```

Later...

```
UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[button viewWithTag:1000];
```

If there's no way for you to set the `tag`, you can also loop over the button's subviews, looking for an instance of `UILabel`:

```
UILabel *label;
for (NSObject *view in button.subviews) {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
        label = (UILabel *)view;
        break;
    }
}
// Do stuff with label
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but is there any other way in case you don't have a reference to it?