# Can I *replace* the UILabel on a UIButton with FXLabel?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uibutton, uilabel

So, I'm trying to change the `UILabel` on a `UIButton` to an instance of an `FXLabel` instead. Check out the link for more on `FXLabel` (https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXLabel). I know by using class extensions ([Subclass UIButton to add a property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500327/subclass-uibutton-to-add-a-property)), I could always add another property, in my case, an `FXLabel` by just adding a subview basically. However, I like the convenience and features of the `titleLabel` property already present.

Is there some method to "switch" the `UILabel` for an `FXLabel` by subclass or category?

I do know I could do this, but it's such a hack and isn't future proof. And I don't know how to then change the class type ([Get UILabel out of UIButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742138/get-uilabel-out-of-uibutton)).

```
UILabel *label;
for (NSObject *view in button.subviews) {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
        label = (UILabel *)view;
        break;
    }
}
```

Thoughts?? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's another way you could at least access the label.  Create a subclass of `UIButton`, and in that subclass override `layoutSubviews`.  From there you can access the label directly:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    UILabel *titleLabel = [self titleLabel];
}
```

Now we're still stuck with the problem of changing that label to be a subclass.  I guess you could try to dynamically swap the `UILabel`'s class with your `FXLabel` subclass (as detailed [here](http://davedelong.com/blog/2010/10/07/fun-objective-c-dynamic-subclassing)), but to be honest that's pretty risky.

I'd say you're better off just creating your own `UIControl` that you can customize to your hearts content.  No risk, just pure goodness.  It shouldn't be too hard to imitate a simple `UIButton`.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I think I'll just try creating my own custom class. I'll mark this as answering my question if no one else gives me anything better. Thanks!

Comment: I just hacked it and added the label on top of the button without actually setting text on the button. Now I have to keep track of two properties for alpha changes, etc, but it's much easier than trying to create my own UIControl. I'll work on it in the future and see if I get anything

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to say it but I don't think you can do this in any reliable way. Even if you subclassed `UIButton` and overrode the `titleLabel` methods you'd also have to handle the state settings. And you never know when the internal code refers directly to a private ivar for the label.

I created a subclass of UIButton for my apps to do something similar (custom button layouts & subviews), sorry I can't share it right now, it's owned by a client. It's not too difficult to create your own state handling code for your own subviews.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll see what I can put together.